# How to get the Total Total-Time for a method using VisualVM

Tags: java, profiling, metrics, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am trying to measure the performance increase of inlining an accessor into a function.

As a consequence of the inlining, the self-time of the method increases (of course).

I need to measure the Total Time and invocations of the method. In VisualVM The profiler lists total self-time, and the snapshot can gives the total-time for each position in the call tree. What I need to measure is the Total Total-Time across the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default performance tweaking disclaimer: Are you sure you need to inline a method? The JVM (since v1.6) does this automatically when needed. It is very rare that you want to inline a function in java.

VisualVM allows you to define which classes are measured. If you define only the calling class (in which you inlined the function), or at least exclude the class that you want to inline a function from, all called functions are then added to 'self time'.

Comment: Thanks, when I create a preset that limits the profile to the class I am interested in, I only get one entry for the function in the call tree.. which has all the stats I need, thanks.